# Nagios monitored servers inventory

Tags: nagios

has anyone from you pulled server hardware data from Nagios to build an inventory? Basically I am trying to create an inventory of an existing servers and hardware components monitored with nagios (i.e. hostname, CPU, MEM, HDD and etc.) There are other ways to do it, but maybe there is a plugin or a way to pull it directly from nagios?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could run this on the command line against your configuration files:

```
grep "host_name" /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/hosts.cfg >>output.log
```

That will output a list of all parameters associated with the host_name line within your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new mk_inventory plugin for nagios which will pull HW info from the machine